# exec() string function in python

Tags: python, exec

I try to run commands stored as string in a dictionary, I wonder why this returns None:

```
import psutil

mycode = 'psutil.cpu_count()'
value = exec(mycode)
print(value)
```

---

this returns the correct value:

```
value = psutil.cpu_count()
print(value)
```

ty

Comment: Because `exec` always returns `None`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval` instead of `exec` check below code:

```
import psutil

mycode = 'psutil.cpu_count()'
value = eval(mycode)
print(value)
```

Comment: thank you so much Amit, sorry I can't upvote - too low reputation

Answer (score 0):

Try to store result of you code into variable:

```
import psutil

result = 0
mycode = 'result = psutil.cpu_count()'
exec(mycode)
print(result)
```